# Does Visual Studio 2010 on x64 crash often? Or is it just on my PC?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

MY VS2010 crashes dozens of times a day.  Compare that to 2008 and 2005 which were rock solid.

Is 2010 known to be susceptible to crashing? Or could it be my environment? I'm using x64 as a dev box for the first time.  The only plugin I has so far is Ankh.

It crashes when doing different things.  One I've noticed so far that always happens is if I press the key sequence alt-f-s-up (or any cursor key) it will crash every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The older versions of AnkSVN had a bug that caused constant crashing in VS2010 (1x per hour or more).  Upgrade to 2.1.8420 or later.

Comment: Upgraded - will see if it crashes today or not.  The alt-f-s-cursor key combo does not cause it to crash anymore.

Comment: 1 week later - and VS2010 has been very stable all week.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It never crashes on my laptop. But still I find it slower than VS2008. Maybe because of the new powerful features.

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 is solid for me on x64.

Is that key sequence tied to Ankh? If so that might be the cause.  Does this sequence also crash VS if you use it in a new project?

Comment: Heh no.. its alt-file-save ;) I use the keyboard 99% of the time and try not to touch the mouse, it wastes time to switch back n forth between keyboard and mouse.  So the cursor key is because I'm already moving to the next place I want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

No crashes here, been running VS2010 on Win7x64 for quite awhile.  Are you using version control? Try removing that plugin you mentioned, at least for a while, to see if the crash rate changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had around 5 crashes last few days on Win7 Pro x64. And it happend without any concrete reason...

Answer (score 0):

I found intresting page http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/thread/288025. 
This problem can appear with Resharper 5 and TODO statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Mine freezes the whole system on debugging from time to time. It may freeze when I start debugging for a program or after some time the debugging has been started.

Here is what I found:
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2010/01/06/visual-studio-2010-beta2-hang-while-debugging.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/debugger/visual-studio-2010-beta2-hang-while-debugging)

I have disabled the IntelliTrace, but today got another hang.